# Circle in latex

Tags: arc

I am completely new to latex. Was trying to make a circle but was not really what I wished to make. Please help and thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3] 
        \coordinate (0,0) node[left] (O) {O};
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1.3,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw (0,0) circle(1cm); 
        \fill (63:1) circle(1pt);
        \draw (0,0)--(63:1) node[midway,left] () {$V$}; 
        \draw[dashed] ({cos(63)},0)--(63:1);
        \draw[latex-latex] (1.12,0) arc (0:63:1.12) node[midway,fill=white] () {$V$};
        \node at (63:1.2) (a) {P$(x,y)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

ADD: For a more complete picture:

[image]

put this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3] 
        \coordinate (0,0) node[above left] (O) {O};
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1.3,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw (0,0) circle(1cm); 
        \fill (63:1) circle(1pt);
        \draw (0,0)--(63:1) node[midway,left] () {$V$}; 
        \draw[dashed] ({cos(63)},0)--(63:1);
        \draw[latex-latex] (1.12,0) arc (0:63:1.12) node[midway,fill=white] () {$V$};
        \node at (63:1.2) (a) {P$(x,y)$};
        \draw[-latex] (.25,0) arc(0:63:.25) node[midway,right] () {1 radiant};
        \draw[-latex] (.2,0) arc(0:360:.2) node[pos=.75,below] () {$2\pi$ radiants};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: For a more realistic picture change the value '63' to '57.3' (1 radiant in degree) everywhere in the code above.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sophia N. You could also vote and accept my work.